# Css3d and point coordinates

Tags: javascript, math, css-transforms

I was wondering, how can I calculate the coordinates of the points a,b,c,d given the transform data (perspective, rotationXYZ, translateXYZ) of the div?

[image]

Also, shame on me, as I'm not a math genius :\ Is there any chance to find even partial code around to help? Something ported from actionscript maybe?

TIA!

EDIT: Basically what i'm trying to achieve is the opposite of [this beauty](http://goo.gl/5Khuos), but I am not smart enough to reverse it :|

Comment: Please elaborate by an example of the input data for  perspective, rotationXYZ and translateXYZ of div.

Comment: Do want the coordinates in reference to the parent, the window, or the screen? What have you tried?

Comment: to the window would be perfect.